# SQL AUTO_INCREMENT starting at number

Tags: mysql, sql

am on a MySQL database and am using MySQL workbench.

here's my table DDL

```
CREATE TABLE `contract_validator` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I want to make an id column in a table auto_increment, i did so using

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
ALTER TABLE validator MODIFY id bigint AUTO_INCREMENT;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

I have two issues, i want to set the auto_increment to max(id) + 1

i have tried:

```
SELECT @validator_id := max(id) + 1 FROM validator; 
ALTER TABLE validator AUTO_INCREMENT = @validator_id ;
```

but i get syntax error,
the second issue is that when i try to insert a line i get an error

```
Error Code: 1364. Field 'id' doesn't have a default value
```

I don't know what I did wrong,

thank you for your help.

Comment: max(id) +1 ? what does that mean? Can you explain what value range you want

Comment: Are you messing with ID's and autoincrement value is smaller with actual max ID?

Comment: Can you add the syntax error you get with alter table to your question ?

Comment: the table already have records inserted, so by max(id) + 1 i want to get the latest Id and icrement it by 1,

Comment: sorry if i failed to describe the issue, for example last inserted id is 100, by running max(id) + 1 i would get 101 so that will be the next value that auto_increment should use

Comment: I doubt if you have to do anything other than modify the column otherwise there would be a chance of duplicate errors arising.

Comment: This is actually the default behaviour (e.g. the next id will be max id +1 anyway). Can you clarify what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Please add the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE validator;`  (using [edit])   Or rightclick on table, 'Table inspector', and the contents of the tab `DDL`

Comment: BTW:  "CREATE TABLE `contract_validator`"   and "ALTER TABLE validator"   WHY ?

Comment: Please also show the insert statement which is causing the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, you don't have to take care of AUTO_inCREMENT value.

When you update id column to make it auto increment, MySQL will automatically set AUTO_INCREMENT value to the MAX + 1 value, event if there  are gaps in in column numerotation.

SQL for setting auto increment on id field:

```
ALTER TABLE `test` CHANGE `id` `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, add PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
```

Comment: okay thank you, but when i try to insert a new record i get Error Code: 1364. Field 'id' doesn't have a default value
error

Comment: I have add SQL statement to make column auto increment.

Comment: Take a look at this fiddle example : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0a802c841eeab17b47750aeab89a1d6a